# Facing issue on Autowiring a SpringBoot bean inside an AttributeConverter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, autowired

I'm having a Spring Boot application that uses two databases, and hence, have manually configured entity manager and other DB configurations.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = ["testApp.repository"]
)
class TestAppDbConfig {
    protected static Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update")
        props.put("properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", true)
        props.put("properties.hibernate.dialect", MySQL5InnoDBDialect.getName());
        props.put("properties.hibernate.format_sql", false);
        props.put("properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone", "Asia/Kolkata");
        props.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        return props;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
    ) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("testApp")
                .persistenceUnit("testPU")
                .properties(jpaProperties())
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

The secondary database config is also completely same except custom names for each of the beans, datasource prefix inside configuration properties and @Primary annotation on all the beans.

On top of this, I have a EncryptionUtility as follows:

```
@Component
class EncryptionUtil {
    // member variables to be used inside encrypt & decrypt
    
    EncryptionUtil(
            @Value('${encryption.key}') String password,
            @Value('${encryption.iv}') String iv
    ) {}
    
    byte[] encrypt(String plainText) {
        // encrypts the string to AES256
    }
    
    String decrypt(byte[] encryptedText) {
        // decrypts the string using AES256
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this inside an AttributeConverter in order to encrypt the data and store in DB. The AttributeConverter is as follows:

```
@Converter
class EncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, byte[]> {
    @Autowired
    EncryptionUtil encryptionUtil

    @Override
    byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        return encryptionUtil.encrypt(attribute)
    }

    @Override
    String convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
        return encryptionUtil.decrypt(dbData)
    }
}
```

The application gets up and running; but when an object of the respective entity is being persisted, it goes inside AttributeConverter and finds **encryptionUtil** to be `null`.

The converter fails and the data doesn't get persisted inside DB.

Tried following things to resolve this:

1. Replacing `@Converter` annotation in EncryptionConverter by `@Component` to make converter as a Spring bean that gets managed by SpringBoot.
2. Tried implementing `ApplicationContextAware` to retreive EncryptionConverter bean from the application context manually.
3. Tried using `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` to manually autowire this.

Not sure of the exact issue but it seems there's something that I've missed that's leading to some inconsistency between Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: You need both `@Converter` **and** `@Component` for the convert (or an `@Bean` method instead of `@Component`).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried this but its still not working

Comment: Just a suggestion : EncryptionUtility could've been developed & used in a more utility like fashion i.e. I would've created encrypt and decrypt method as static methods so that these methods could be used without the instance of EncryptionUtility.

Comment: That is not in your list of things you tried you stated replaced not added. Nonetheless the converter needs to be spring managed else it will simply not work.